# Detect Background and Accent colour in Windows Phone 7 web

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to detect the Background and Accent colour in Windows Phone 7 using web technologies like JavaScript and change the colours in my CSS accordingly?
I've looked everywhere without any success!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to interact with the phone OS using javascript (or any technology supported by the phone's web browser). So either the information is available in the user-agent (and I'm pretty sure it isn't), or you can't do that.

If you're using the WebBrowser control inside of a phone app, there's probably a few workarounds. But for the native internet explorer app there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to access the accent color directly via CSS: use the property `Highlight`. This way, you can also access the accent color in Windows Phone 8 Apps written in HTML5. In other Browsers, for example Safari, `Highlight` will result in the Highlight color, of course...
To get the suitable Text color in native HTML5 Apps, `HighlightText` can be used. As for my Tests, this doesn't work in Windows Phone 7 and results in black anyway.